# Running a piece of code when Notification deleted

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out how to run a piece of code when a notification gets cleared.
I've found that the Notification class provides a deleteIntent which is run when the notification is cleared, but I have been unable to find any resource that explains how I could go about getting this to run a piece of code within my application.

I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions of how I could achieve this, or could point me towards a good tutorial that will explain how I could go about achieving this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I have been unable to find any resource that explains how I could go about getting this to run a piece of code within my application.

A `PendingIntent` can either do:

- `startActivity()` on an `Intent` that you supply, or
- `startService()` on an `Intent` that you supply, or
- `sendBroadcast()` on an `Intent` that you supply

Since you probably already have a service (otherwise, I'm not sure why you have a `Notification` in the first place), I'd use the second option. Use the `getService()` static method on `PendingIntent`, handing it an `Intent` identifying your service. When the user gets rid of the `Notification`, your service will be called with `onStartCommand()`.